# Can I use Blender's Python API from a Python IDE?

Tags: python

Is it possible to use Blender's Python API scripting directly from Python IDE? If so, how?.  I was looking forward to something that would allow me to help develop a game completely using python.

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want to do so we can help you better!

Comment: You can write python code anywhere you want, but you have to run it in blender.

Answer (score 7):

You can develop Blender Python add-ons from external IDE's easily, and without compiling Blender as a Python module. The often referenced method of compiling Blender as a Python module has long been defunct, and only works for certain OS's.

Most add-on developers work by opening a project in the `2.8x/scripts/addons/` directory of their Blender installation. From here, you can develop directly in Blender's filesystem from your favorite IDE, then hit <kbd>F8</kbd> in Blender to refresh/re-compile your add-on live.

See this post for a more detailed discussion: [The Best Way to Develop Blender Python Add-ons](https://chrisconlan.com/best-way-develop-blender-python-add-ons/)

---

<kbd>F8</kbd> refreshes the addon list. To bind it to a hotkey in 2.8, insert the command `preferences.addon_refresh`.

[image: addon refresh hotkey]

Answer (score 1):

you should install blender as a python module

see this tutorial : https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule